# Whats the wrong with Select Option Validation

Tags: jquery, validation

Hi I am using Jquery Validation here define user define required function for select option,

Added validation when its value is -1. But still message is not displayed as  **Please Select Technology**. Please help whats the wrong with this code

```
var reportValidator = $("#categoryForm").validate({
rules: {                            
        reportType: "required",
        productionLine:{
        required: function(element) {
                if( $("#productionLine").val()== "-1"){                    
                return false;
            }else{                    
                return true;
            }



        }
    },
        userIds: "required"
},      
errorElement: "span" ,  
errorPlacement: function(error, element) {

         if (element.attr("name") == "reportType"){
             error.insertAfter("#reportError");     
         }else{
           error.insertAfter(element);
         }
       },
    messages: {
        reportType: " Please Select Report Type",
        productionLine : " Please Select Technology",           
        userIds: " Please Select User Ids"
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want validation when its value is -1 then you must change the return values (true <-->false)